# How to read input until EOF in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eof

How do I read an input stream until EOF in Lisp? In C, you might do it like this:

```c
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
  // Loop body...
}
```

I would like to be able to pipe data to my Lisp programs without having to specify the data size in advance. Here's an example from something I'm doing now:

```lisp
(dotimes (i *n*)
  (setf *t* (parse-integer (read-line) :junk-allowed T))
  (if (= (mod *t* *k*) 0) (incf *count*)))
```

In this loop, the variable `*n*` specifies the number of lines I'm piping to the program (the value is read from the first line of input), but I would like to just process an arbitrary and unknown number of lines, stopping when it reaches the end of the stream.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`read-line` takes an optional argument (`eof-error-p`) allowing it to return either `NIL` (default) or a user-specified value (`eof-value`) on hitting an `EOF`, instead of signalling an error.

From [Chapter 19 of Successful Lisp](https://web.archive.org/web/20090307235341/http://psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter19.html):

> READ-LINE *&optional stream eof-error-p eof-value recursive-p*
>
> In the read functions listed above, optional arguments `EOF-ERROR-P` and `EOF-VALUE` specify what happens when your program makes an attempt to read from an exhausted stream. If `EOF-ERROR-P` is true (the default), then Lisp will signal an error upon an attempt to read an exhausted stream. If `EOF-ERROR-P` is NIL, then Lisp returns `EOF-VALUE` (default `NIL`) instead of signalling an error.

You can use this as a simple termination condition for your function.

Comment: @GustavBertram Not sure what you mean. It is still available for download from the link I posted over seven years ago in this answer. I just confirmed.

Answer (score 15):

See the HyperSpec for [READ-LINE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm)

```
(loop for line = (read-line stream nil :eof) ; stream, no error, :eof value
      until (eq line :eof)
      do ... )
```

or sometimes with nil

```
(loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
      while line
      do ... )
```